# Having multiple desktop sessions on MacOS with same user

Tags: macos

I have a shared Mac system running on BigSur 11.4 - which I access from office and home. I have a single user id, and do not want the two sessions to interfere with each other. Can I have 2 independent sessions on this Mac machine for the same user ? Basically, I am seeking guidance on ‘what kind of options/settings/helper applications' will allow me to do this. Thanks in advance.

Comment: I'm not sure how this would work. If the same use has the same file open for edit in two independent sessions, which version of the file is correct?

Comment: Please don't cross-post to multiple SE sites. Pick one & stick to it, or flag for migration. 
[Is cross-posting a question on multiple Stack Exchange sites permitted if the question is on-topic for each site?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/64068/) - https://superuser.com/questions/1698572/having-multiple-desktop-sessions-on-macos-with-same-user

Comment: I'd love something like this. Basically I have an overly complex (yet I can't seem to cope without it) 3 monitor setup with loads of Spaces, and I want to be able to take the Mac somewhere else and have a different set of Spaces. Essentially two different sessions with the same user. Without this my Spaces are a mess when its just one screen. I realise it's quite edge case though :-)